# How to monitor all outgoing http calls from my debian linux server?

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I'm using a service to manage my users who charges me per api call. 
Lately the api calls has increased greatly and I want to

log to file or to sttout all the outgoing http calls from the server (debian)

In my localhost I've done this with hacks using `mitmproxy`

obviously , I can't do it in my production server.

How can I log the `https` calls and then grep only the relevant ones ?

Comment: I believe you’re going about this the wrong way. Surely you know what causes an API call to be made and also which program does it. That’s where you need to start looking.

Comment: hi Daniel, Their api client is causing the api calls, obviously. BUT, it's a wrapper around the actual api calls so I don't know exactly how many and how to catch them all in one place?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have root priviledges on your production server.

You can try using `tcpdump`, log the output to file and then parse/filter it as you see fit with tools like `grep`, `sed` etc...

Please note that `tcpdump` includes a failrly complex and complete set of filtering options, so be sure to check the man page.

This is a sample command to log all outgoing https requests (run as root):

```
tcpdump -s 0 'tcp dst port 443'
```